# Instantiating from file : constructor taking std:ifstream& as argument

Tags: c++

I wish to have a class constructor to read values from a file so I define a class like this:

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<fstream> 
#include<string>

class aClass
{
    float value;
public:
    aClass(float v) : value(v) {}
    aClass(const aClass& other): value(other.value) {}
    static aClass initFromFile(std::ifstream &); 
};

aClass initFromFile(std::ifstream &is)
{ 
    std::string strBuffer;
    std::getline(is, strBuffer);
    float v = std::stof(strBuffer);
    return aClass(v);
}
```

My question is about the `static initFromFile` constructor.

The main program would then open a file, read a value and instantiate the class:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile("value.txt");
    aClass cls(aClass::initFromFile(inFile));
}
```

The code compiles, but there is an error when linking:

```
undefined reference to `aClass::initFromFile(std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
```

Why is `inFile` not `std::ifstream`?

Comment: You missed the scope resolution in the function implementation. `aClass initFromFile(std::ifstream &is)` should be `aClass aClass::initFromFile(std::ifstream &is)`. Without the `aClass::` you get a whole new function that isn't related to the class. Come to think of it, there doesn't seem to be a need for this function to be a class member. It can stand alone as a free function.

Comment: Unrelated: if you `static aClass initFromFile(std::istream &);` you can use the function to read from any input stream, `cin`, `ifstream`, `istringstream`, or what-have-you.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments:

```
aClass initFromFile(std::ifstream &is) {}
```

is a definition of a free (non-member) function. You want

```
aClass aClass::initFromFile(std::ifstream &is)
```

instead.

Also, your copy constructor is useless and can be removed. Implicitly generated one will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have misinterpreted the error. It has nothing to do with whether or not `inFile` is a `std::ifstream` or not (it is). The problem is in the implementation of the `initFromFile` function.

```
aClass initFromFile(std::ifstream &is)
{
    ... 
}
```

Declares a new function that is not related to `aClass`. In order for the compiler to know that `initFromFile` is indeed `aClass::initFromFile`, you'll have to tell it:

```
aClass aClass::initFromFile(std::ifstream &is)
//     ^^^^^^^^
{
    ... 
}
```

However, `initFromFile` makes no use of the class internals, so the general rule of thumb is that it should not be a member of the class.

```
class aClass
{
    float value;
public:
    aClass(float v) : value(v) {}
    aClass(const aClass& other): value(other.value) {}
};

aClass initFromFile(std::ifstream &is) //stand-alone free function
{ 
    std::string strBuffer;
    std::getline(is, strBuffer);
    float v = std::stof(strBuffer);
    return aClass(v);
}
```

It can be used as

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile("value.txt");
    aClass cls = initFromFile(inFile);
}
```

Unrelated notes:

A minor improvement is to define `initFromFile` using a `std::istream`

```
aClass initFromFile(std::istream &is)
```

so that you can use the function with a wider variety of streams such as `cin`.

Also familiarize yourself with the [Rules of Three, five and Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). `aClass` qualifies for the Rule of Zero, and thus needs no user-defined copy constructor.

Comment: Thank you for all these information!  I'll make good use of them. Especially the `std::istream` suggestion!

Comment: Also, making it part of the class, doesn't it make polymorphism more straigth forward?  Such that different classes could have a `initFromFile` method? (without having to include the class in the method name)

Comment: I just got it: the prototype contains the returned type information (new to C++, getting acquainted ;-).

Comment: @MartN For polymorphism to work, you need to use references (read up on "object slicing" for why), and if you are passing references around you have to make sure what the reference refers to is still alive. You can still do it, but you'd likely wind up with something more like `std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> aClass::initFromFile(std::istream &is)`